How can I mount /proc/sys/net read-write in a Docker container?
The release notes for Docker 27.0.1 say:

Other workarounds are to configure the OS to disable IPv6 by default on new interfaces, mount /proc/sys/net read-write, or use a kernel with no IPv6 support.

How can I apply that second workaround?
I tried specifying --volume /proc/sys/net:/proc/sys/net:rw but the run aborted with “[…] cannot be mounted because it is inside /proc”. I imagine that --privileged would “solve” this but is there a way to avoid resorting to the nuclear option?

The easiest option for setting sysctl values in a container is to use the --sysctl option to docker run.
For example, compare this:
$ docker run --rm docker.io/alpine:latest ip addr show lo
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

With the following, which sets net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1:
$ docker run -it --rm --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1 docker.io/alpine:latest ip addr show lo
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


Thank you, but if I understand correctly you’re suggesting that I apply the first workaround, not the second as I asked. If you believe that the second workaround is impossible, it’s okay to say that, and indeed a more helpful answer than dodging the question.

"Dodging the question?" I think that's uncalled for. I'm sorry if you didn't find this answer helpful.

Thank you again for trying to be helpful, but this answer as written doesn’t address the question.
